# vim :match regexp

Tags: regex, vim

i want to match a non valid C/C++ line that's why i use the regexp below

```
/^[^#].+(.+[^;(){}])$/
```

with the cmd `:match errorMsg` :
and my regular validate some simple conditions
a line that :

1. starts without `#` (preprocessor cmds)
2. does not end with a `;,(),{}`

will be considered as uncorrect line

but it does not work any help

Comment: `[^;(){}]` matches a character that isn't any of those characters, it doesn't looks for sequences like `()` and `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/\v^[^#].*$([;(){}])@<!/
```

*Details*:

- `\v` - the very magic mode to avoid overescaping special pattern chars
- `^` - start of a line
- `[^#]` - any char other than `#` (not matching line breaks in Vim)
- `.*$` - the rest of a line, zero or more chars (`.*`) and end of line (`$`)
- `([;(){}])@<!` - a [negative lookbehind](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Regex_lookahead_and_lookbehind), no `;`, `(`, `)`, `{` and `}` are allowed right at the end of string.

This is [this pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/qoxqFb/1) (converted to PCRE just for demo purposes).

It works in Vim:

[image]

with the file contents like

```
abc match me
abc no match;
match
# def no MATCH{}
}
{
(
)
;
```

Comment: tnx sir that works for me but i wanna ask you ,which book can i read for experting vim .

Comment: @DragoBan As for Vim regex, there is hardly a book that can help. The [Vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/), [Vim fandom patterns](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_patterns), [Vim regex](https://learnbyexample.gitbooks.io/vim-reference/content/Regular_Expressions.html) on Gitbooks should be helpful, and [Vim documentation: pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html) and [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression) are extensive Vim regex references.

Comment: @DragoBan Also, I have started a ["Regex Quickies" Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw), where you can learn more about regex in general.